# Running ActiveJDBC instrumentation on Play Framework compilation

Tags: maven, playframework, playframework-2.0, activejdbc

I'm trying to use ActiveJDBC with Play framework. It requires special Instrumentation plugin to be ran on startup.

I'm also using Maven with my application.

How can I run my application with instrumentation plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Not too familiar with Play, but ActiveJDBC can be instrumented with a variety of methods, Maven plugin is only one such method. See here: http://javalt.org/p/instrumentation for more information. All you have to do is instrument ActiveJDBC models before you start Play.

Comment: I've executed `mvn activejdbc-instrumentation:instrument play2:run`, but error still occures

Comment: it is possible that play recompiles all model classes